# Set viewport perspective using walkthrough?

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

Sometimes, I find it easiest to position my 3D viewport perspective using either the walk or fly through mode.  I find it less clunky than the usual 3D port navigation tools.  This is especially true if I'm trying to match my perspective to a photograph.

But when I exit walk/fly navigation after positioning everything how I want it, it snaps back to the position the viewport was in before I started navigation.  I want it to just stay put.

I'm not talking about moving cameras, I'm just talking about the 3D viewport perspective.

I'm essentially asking the same thing as in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124816/using-walk-navigation-like-unity-and-unreal), but that one has no working answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the current position when using fly or walk viewport navigation, simply left-click when you are happy with the position. This will keep the current view.

As seen in this image
[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you!  I was pressing "ESC" which I guess meant "cancel". I should have read the little tool strip!